# How to load image in ios using swift language in table view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am building a timeline ios app using swift language.
I am able to print content like username in table view controller after fetched from mysql database using php and json
but not able to fetch images .

Please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use an NSUrlConnection on a background thread to load images, or you could use a library like HanekeSwift or SDWebImage for example.

Comment: i have tried lots of example but not got succeed. actually i am new in ios development. I am building app like facebook or twitter timeline type.can u suggest some good examples?

Comment: If you are looking for examples/tutorials. Try google. Then once you have found some. Try them out. See how they work. Then break down your project into smaller parts. Then look for tutorials that focus on that part of your project. Read, Learn and read some more. Then once you have some code and are stuck. Post a well written question with some snippets of your code where you are stuck. Goodluck.